# It's a serial killer!

Tags: wordplay, mystery

So there was a call. To a food store.

You pick it up.

> Hello, this is Costco? (not an ad, sry)
>
> We have a serial killer!!! (Female voice.)
>
> What?!?! Is this a prank....!
>
> It's OJ...[unknown]..! (Sounds like a boy? A son? It is so unclear the rest is cut off.)
>
> (screams)
>
> (distant shout) What did you do?!?!?!

At this point, your shaking, and you decide too take the phone number and give it to the police.

After about 5 minutes, you get another call from the police.

> It was all a misunderstanding... (sounds amused)
>
> But, but, sir, she said-
>
> Yes.

He chuckles.

What are his next words?

Comment: Cereal killer???

Comment: Orange Juice???

Comment: Puzzle inspired by?: [Documentary: Serial killer, not O.J., killed Simpson and Goldman](http://www.cnn.com/2012/11/20/justice/o-j-simpson-film-claim/)

Answer (score 1):

He said:

> [Silly rabbit, Trix are for kids.](https://youtu.be/q8StT5oVECM)

Reasoning:

> The Costco phone answerer misheard in the phone when the kids said "cereal" on the prank call.  OJ refers to the orange juice that someone would drink with their breakfast (a meal at which one would eat cereal)

Comment: What's your reasoning for this?

Comment: @Inazuma I thought it was obvious.  Context added.

Comment: I have never heard that phrase, but maybe I'm too young (considering it was made in 1997)

Comment: I will accept it if you put in the OJ clue..... this is obviously the best!

Answer (score 1):

May be:

> At first it was a call from police station of a lady(as given a female voice),who was trying to tell they caught a **cereal killer** but then the call cut off which was misunderstood as serial killer by Costco.
>
> Again it was the call from same lady from police station as given **she** in the statement "*But, but, sir, **she** said*".
>
> This time she told it was a misunderstanding ,they caught a kid (named OJ) who stole **cereals** from there store(a cereal killer).

Comment: Congrats! You got it.

Answer (score 1):

> Orange Juice was killing the cereal.

perhaps making it soggy.

Comment: Well, it's certainly gets all the clues!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

> The supposed serial killer is really a cereal killer. The killing was done by the milk making it soggy. And the OJ followed by screaming and "What did you do?!?!?!" could be someone knocked over a glass of orange juice, at which even I would shout what did you do.

Comment: Ahh, this is correct and creative. But the best goes to LeppyR64.

Answer (score 0):

He said most probably his close ones played a prank on him.Because if there was some some serial killer the victims would have first tried calling cops.

Comment: No.... not that.